# SAS proc format statement

Tags: sas

I want to create a format on a numeric variable (say, age) to see the result as ">10". I tried as:

```
PROC FORMAT;
  VALUE agefmt 
    >10 - high  = '> 10'     /*10 to be excluded.*/
    other      = '<= 10'
    ;
RUN;
```

But it does not work. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made just a small mistake, the > must be < and between the values:

```
 PROC FORMAT;
   VALUE agefmt 
     10 <- high  = '> 10'     /*10 to be excluded.*/
     other      = '<= 10'
   ;
RUN;
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.